# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model.pkl' in python deploying webapp

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

[image]

I have a file Fake_News_Det.py , where I have :

```
loaded_model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', "rb"))
```

When I run my python server where analyze.py is called, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Dipesh\Fake_News_Detection\Interpreter\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Dipesh/Fake_News_Detection/Fake_News_Det.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dipesh/Fake_News_Detection/Fake_News_Det.py", line 12, in <module>
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', "rb"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model.pkl'
```

[image]
Fake_News_Det.py and model.pkl are both in the same directory. So, it is not the path issue. Could you tell how to solve this error?

Comment: It all depends upon from where you're running your python script. It's always recommended to use Absolute Path.

Comment: @Oli can you guide me what exactly should be the path so that it would run

Comment: Hey, you can read about how to use absolute path in python.

Comment: If you don't want to use the absolute path to the file you can try setting it as source or resource root [see the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html).